# Facebook Like - Display counter starting at Zero?

Tags: facebook

I got frustrated with the number of "Like" plugins available, so I went straight to Facebook for a direct implementation.

I want my like button to look like how how its displayed on Techcrunch (example: http://techcrunch.com/2011/03/09/report-paypals-express-checkout-helps-bump-sales-by-18-percent/) - Notice the Facebook Like button - The word like, then a box to the right with the "like count".

I've copied the code and modified it as follows:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80;&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=20" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:20px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The code above displays the "Like" button, but without the counter (I want it to display, even at zero).

I may be missing something simple - Any ideas?

Comment: Short of using JS i don't think you can, the Facebook API determines what is rendered inside that iframe.. (it's not generated on the local server)..

Comment: Here's a good post for what you're trying to do
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476603/show-zero-in-button-count-like-button

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I do not think there is a way to do this. I believe I also read somewhere that modifying the Like button is against Facebook's Terms of Service, so I would suggest not trying to go that route.

Ultimately, Facebook decides what gets shown. You could set a background image under the like button with a little 0 poking out of the right side in the same style, that's the only thing I could think of to do.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to I can think of to get it to display 0 likes is if it doesnt have any likes at all, other wise your SOL buddy.

Comment: The trouble is that when there are not any likes, it doesn't display zero :). Its just blank. I would _like_ it to display zero when there are not any likes.